# split one column into multiple columns usining delimiter

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, split

i have a dataframe that have one of its filed contains multiple values separated by "+".
What i want is to  split each value into a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': [3009, 129, 119, 120, 121],
  'date': ['2016+2017', '2015', '2014+2019+2020', '2020', 'NULL']
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

LOOK like this:

```
df    

Out[25]: 
      ID       date
0    3009    2016+2017
1     129    2015
2     119    2014+2019+2020
3     120    2020
4     121    NULL
```

I want to split the column 'date' by the '+' delimiter and create columns based on the number of existing  delimiters then create a columns that display the number of dates for each record.

```
      ID     date   date2    date3  number of dates
0     3009   2016   2017     NULL     2
1     129    2015   NULL     NULL     1
2     119    2014   2019     2020     3
3     120    2020   NULL     NULL     1
4     121    NULL   NULL     NULL     0
```

I tried this code:

```
df["date"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("+")))
```

but it crush and display the below error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: df['date'].str.split('+', expand=True)

Comment: to get the counts, use `.count(...)`

Comment: i tried you suggestion but it display this error`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: how to use the count to get the number ??

Comment: I changed your suggestion  into 
`df[["date","date2","date3"]] = df.date.str.split('+',expand = True)`
and works

Comment: please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split` to split

```
df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']] = df['date'].replace('NULL', np.nan).str.split('+', expand=True)
```

and `count` to count

```
df['number of dates'] = df[['date', 'date2', 'date3']].count(axis=1)

print(df)

     ID  date date2 date3  number of dates
0  3009  2016  2017  None                2
1   129  2015  None  None                1
2   119  2014  2019  2020                3
3   120  2020  None  None                1
4   121   NaN   NaN   NaN                0
```

Comment: You are welcome. I added `.replace('NULL', np.nan)` so the count won't count 'NULL'.